# Next/Previous Entry Linking works on some entries but not others

Tags: embeds, next-prev

I setup the next/previous entry linking code in an embed because it is positioned within a channel entries tag in the template. Same template, some entries display the links fine, and others don't. Can't figure out why it works for some and not others.

Template debugging says: Channel Next/Prev Entry tag error: Could not resolve single entry page id. But i don't know why.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="artists" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields|pagination" dynamic="yes"}
    {embed="artists/.next_prev"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

.next_prev embed:

```
        {exp:channel:next_entry}
            <p>Next: <a href="{path='artists'}">{title}</a></p>
        {/exp:channel:next_entry}
        {exp:channel:prev_entry}
            <p>Previous: <a href="{path='artists'}">{title}</a></p>
        {/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the [channel parameter](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_linking.html#channel) into your next and prev entry tags.

I would also look into the [url_title parameter](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_linking.html#url-title) because you are embedding these. Just get the segment that has your entries url title

Comment: The channel parameter got it working...kind of weird that without it some entries would work ok and some wouldn't. Thanks!